# Jquery remove duplicates with the same html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, duplicates

I'm working on "removing duplicates" from html with jQuery. An example is the following:

```
<p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">something else</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">some more content</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">some more content</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">content</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">this is no duplicate</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">this is no duplicate</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">last p tag finally</p>
```

What I would like to end up with is:

```
 <p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
 <p class="duplicateRemove">something else</p>
 <p class="duplicateRemove">some more content</p>
 <p class="duplicateRemove">content</p>
 <p class="duplicateRemove">this is no duplicate</p>
 <p class="duplicateRemove">last p tag finally</p>
```

So every element to check has the same class and I want to remove the element, when the `html()` is the same.

Can anybody help me out with that? Can't seem to find anything helpful that jQuery provides for that...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Map` to store seen elements based on the inner html content and use it with jquery `filter` method to filter html based on that map.

```js
const map = new Map()

const filtered = $('.duplicateRemove')
  .filter(function() {
    const html = $(this).html();
    if (map.has(html)) return false;
    else {
      map.set(html)
      return true;
    }
  })

$('body').html(filtered)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">hello</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">something else</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">some more content</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">some more content</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">content</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">this is no duplicate</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">this is no duplicate</p>
<p class="duplicateRemove">last p tag finally</p>
```